# Convert Async task params

Tags: android, string, android-asynctask

I have a method inside `AsyncTask` class which I want to reuse. But it uses the object of type **String... url** which is accessed as url[0],url[1]

> To reuse this function I need create a object of Type **String...** or
>   convert String... to String[]

I did not find any documentation for String...

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
    Thread.currentThread().setName("MetaDataDownloader");

     String jsonStr=metadataDownloader(url);
     //this uses param as url[0] and so on
}
```

Comment: what problem you are getting

Comment: According to this [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and in fact, the inner implementation of varargs in Java is just an array. You can do any operation on `url` as an array. For example, url.length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because AsyncTask by design could receive more than one parameter (hence the [`varargs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)...).

Change your method like this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    Thread.currentThread().setName("MetaDataDownloader");

    // if you want to handle all URLs
    if (urls != null) {
        for (String url : urls) {
            String jsonStr=metadataDownloader(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But urls length is not always 1. It o  varies with different cases. is there a way to convert String... to a String[]

Answer (score 0):

You can create constructor in async task and pass what argument you would like to . Do not use parameters in doInBackground.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this [Java Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs). It's arbitrary number of arguments.

> ou can use a construct called varargs to pass an arbitrary number of values to a method. You use varargs when you don't know how many of a particular type of argument will be passed to the method. It's a shortcut to creating an array manually (the previous method could have used varargs rather than an array).
>
> To use varargs, you follow the type of the last parameter by an ellipsis (three dots, ...), then a space, and the parameter name. The method can then be called with any number of that parameter, including none.

--> to use your `doInBackground(String... url)`, just treat it as `array` of parameters and `cast` it to whatever you like.